# scikit learn and multiprocessing: _pickle.PicklingError: Can't pickle <function

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I am creating pipelines using FeatureUnion in scikit learn to concatenate results of multiple transformer objects. When I use the flag `n_jobs=-1` to make it run on multiple cores, I am having the following error:

_pickle.PicklingError: Can't pickle .preprocessor at 0x10b0df268>: attribute lookup feature_union_model..preprocessor on **main** failed

Any suggestion please?

Comment: Can you please provide some code? It will help us better understand what's going on.

Comment: Is your preprocessor function a lambda? Those guys can't be pickled

Comment: It was all about my preprocessor. Thanks all.